# How do I debug Spring @Value injection that is not working?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a simple spring boot application. I am trying to inject property value which is in application.yaml ,  as in --

```
@Component
public class ZkWatcher implements Watcher {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Value("${spring.cloud.zookeeper.connect-string}")
    private static String CONNECT_STRING;

    ....
}
```

The application.yaml is as follows:

```
server:
  port: 8057
spring:
  application:
    name: ConfigProvider
  cloud:
    zookeeper:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
      connect-string: localhost:2181
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
logging:
  level:
    org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: WARN
    org.hibernate: ERROR

my:
  prop: xyz
```

However the @Value injection is injecting NULL value ! Even if I use any other custom property e.g. "my.prop" the injection is not working. Even the Environment injection is injecting null value. What am I missing here ? Do I need to explicitly source the application.yaml ?

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I don't think you can inject values into a static local variable. if you remove the static, does it still fail?

Comment: Are you maybe creating an instance of ZkWatcher yourself, with the `new` keyword, instead of letting Spring handle the lifecycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you remove `static` keyword from your `CONNECT_STRING` variable and retry-

```
@Component
public class ZkWatcher implements Watcher {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Value("${spring.cloud.zookeeper.connect-string}")
    private String CONNECT_STRING;

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the value injected by @Value cannot be static. If you really want to inject it into a static property, please use spring's @PostConstruct like:

```
@Component
public class Apple {
    private static String color;
    @Value("${color}")
    private String colorInjection ;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        color = this.colorInjection;
    }
}
```